# Angular JS. hide a div inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know how to hide a progress bar which I have in a `ng-repeat`. I think I have to use `ng-hide` but maybe it doesn't work because I have many iterations and a `div` with the same ID for `ng-hide`. I want to show that `div` when the user clicks on a button.

How can I do this? thank you

Daniel.

---

Edit.
To be honest, I didn't do it what I asked above because  I expected other behavior of   AngularJS  but I've written now what I wanted on Plunker and it works.

What I wanted is (simplifying) two columns: one column with a button and the other one with a progress bar. If I clic on the button of that row, its progress bar is showed. I thought AngujarJS would show ALL progress bars because all bars have the same tag (ng-hide="bar", for example) and for that reason I opened this question. If someone needs the code, you can see it on Plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/S5b0Dk0Tz7eZCkkJw95j?p=preview

Seeing how AngularJS works, now I wonder how to hide the iteration whose id is 5 if I clic on the botton of iteration whose id is 3. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add some code of what you have so far, preferably in a JSFiddle, and we'll take a look at it for you.

Comment: provide some working sample of your work

Comment: progress bar have any separate class to hide. check once

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I've written the code and it works. But I didn't expect. So if I want to hide a progress bar from other iteration, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could put an attribute isVisible and use ngIf or ngShow for showing and hiding divs here's an example.

#### HTML:

```
<div
  ng-app="app"
  class="main-content"
  ng-controller="MainCtrl as app"
>
  <header class="header">
    <button
      class="button"
      ng-click="app.showAll()"
    >
      Show all
    </button>
    <button
      class="button"
      ng-click="app.hideOdds()"
    >
      Hide odds
    </button>
  </header>
  <div class="elements-container">
    <p
      ng-if="thing.isVisible"
      ng-class="{
        even: thing.even,
        odd: thing.odd
      }"
      ng-repeat="thing in app.stuff"
    >
      {{thing.content}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
(function (angular) {
  var
    app  = angular.module('app',[]),
    MainCtrl = function ($scope) {
      var
        len,
        thing,
        i   = 100,
        app = this;
      app.stuff = [];
      app.showAll = function () {
        len = app.stuff.length - 1;
        for (; len >= 0; len -= 1) {
          app.stuff[len].isVisible = true;
        }
      };
      app.hideOdds = function () {
        len = app.stuff.length - 1;
        for (; len >= 0; len -= 1) {
          if ((app.stuff[len].content % 2) !== 0) {
            app.stuff[len].isVisible = false;
          }
        }
      };
      for (; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        if((i % 2) === 0){
          thing = {
            even: true,
            content: i,
            isVisible: true
          };
        } else {
          thing = {
            odd: true,
            content: i,
            isVisible: false
          };
        }
        app.stuff.push(thing);
      }
    };
  app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
}(this.angular));
```

Hope this help here's a [live demo](http://codepen.io/yahyaKacem/pen/BaKxe).

## update:

If I understand correctly you want when you click the button all progress bars appears, if so  you need just to make the declaration of the bar variable in a higher element inside the controller also it is a best practice to initialize variables in the controller instead of ngInit.
Here's a [fork of your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3cITGrkccbHBZG3m8FxH?p=preview) that does that.

## update 2:

OK, sorry if that was not clear enough here's a more detailed answer:
In the HTML file the first 2 lines from the body tag used to be like this:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-init="vari = [{_id: 2}, {_id: 5}]">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl" ng-repeat="data in vari">
```

I changed them to this:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in vari">
```

In the js file I just added this line:

```
$scope.vari = [{_id: 2}, {_id: 5}];
```

So basically I removed the ngInit directive and moved the initialization to the controller since we need to initialize the `$scope.bar` variable and the controller outside of the ngRepeat scope.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, I didn't speak about hide/show every div, but it also help! Thank you again!

Comment: Check update, hopefully this is what you'r looking for.